# Makefile: Why is 'make' ignoring explicit pattern rule and using implicit rule instead?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following `Makefile`:

```
all: *.o

%.o: %.cc %d
    echo `time` > $*.d
    echo `time` > $@

*.d:
    echo `time` > $@
```

There are no `.d` files and one `test.cc` file. The (partial) output of `make -r all` shows that it ignored the explicit rule. Why?

```
No implicit rule found for `all'.
  Considering target file `test.o'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `test.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `test'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `test.cc'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `testd'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `test'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `test.c'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `test'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `test.cc'.
   Found an implicit rule for `test.o'.
    Considering target file `test.cc'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for `test.cc'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `test.cc'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `test.cc,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `test.cc'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/test.cc,v'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `test.cc'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/test.cc'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `test.cc'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `s.test.cc'.
     Trying pattern rule with stem `test.cc'.
     Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.test.cc'.
     No implicit rule found for `test.cc'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `test.cc'.
    No need to remake target `test.cc'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `test.o'.
   Prerequisite `test.cc' is newer than target `test.o'.
  Must remake target `test.o'.
g++    -c -o test.o test.cc
Putting child 0x01ab52e0 (test.o) PID 2713 on the chain.
Live child 0x01ab52e0 (test.o) PID 2713 
test.cc:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion at end of input
Reaping losing child 0x01ab52e0 PID 2713 
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
Removing child 0x01ab52e0 PID 2713 from chain.
```

---

**Edit**

Here is the new Makefile, with suggestions from the comments. There is still an unanswered question about why a missing prerequisite is not triggering a rule.

```
all: $(patsubst %.cc, %.o, $(wildcard *.cc))

%.o: %.cc

%.o: %.d %.cc
    echo `time` > $*.d
    echo `time` > $@

%.d:
    echo `time` separate > $@
```

Output:

```
  Considering target file `test.o'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `test.o'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `test.d'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
    Trying pattern rule with stem `test'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `test.cc'.
   Found an implicit rule for `test.o'.
    Considering target file `test.cc'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for `test.cc'.
     No implicit rule found for `test.cc'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file `test.cc'.
    No need to remake target `test.cc'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `test.o'.
   Prerequisite `test.d' of target `test.o' does not exist.
   Prerequisite `test.cc' is older than target `test.o'.
  No need to remake target `test.o'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `all'.
```

Comment: There must have been a `test.o` file in the directory also for this to have worked otherwise `*.o` wouldn't have matched anything. Also `*.d` isn't the target you are expecting it to be and I think you meant `%.d` in the prereq of that target. Does fixing those errors (and using something in the `all` prereqs that will actually work correctly like `$(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))` perhaps) help?

Comment: ok I understand the `%d` error and `patsubst` generator. What do mean `*.d` isn't the target you are expecting? @EtanReisner

Comment: I mean the wildcard in a target and prerequisite is `%` which you know from your `%.o: %.cc %.c` target. You just used the wrong wildcard character in the `*.d:` target (unless you meant the target to apply to only existing `.d` files).

Comment: @EtanReisner, I meant `d` not `c` in both rules. What I want to do is ensure a `.d` exists before the rule to make `.o` fires.

Comment: Yes, but the `*.d:` target is incorrect (unless you want it to wildcard against pre-existing `.d` files) and you want `%.d:` instead. I typoed `%.c` in my previous comment I meant `%.d` there. Can you correct your makefile and run it again and then update the post with the corrected makefile and new debug output.

Comment: @EtanReisner, ok I changed it to `%.d` and same result. There's something I'm not understanding about multiple prerequisites. Because if I removed the `%.d` prerequisite the rule fires.

Comment: make prefers targets that can already be built to ones that need intermediates to be built. So your pattern target is losing to the built-in one. [Cancel](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canceling-Rules) the built-in one and that should help.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: I get the right behavior with *make* v4.1 (except I need to mark the `.d` files as `.PRECIOUS`) and the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html) is clear about it: `In order for the pattern rule to apply, its target pattern must match the file name under consideration and all of its prerequisites (after pattern substitution) must name files that exist or can be made.`